# How to multiply a double by a percentage

Tags: java, math

[image]

Hello I was just wondering How I could perform this operation in java?

What I have done is incorrect, I may be looking at this wrong!, some help would be appreciated.

```
double result = n / n * 100 <= 100;
```

Comment: What is that operation? You want to know if a number divided by itself (which is always 1, except for zero) times 100% is less than or equal to 100%? Or something else?

Comment: how to multiply a number in java by 100 percent

Comment: You multiply it by 100 if you want it in percents or do nothing if as just a number.

Comment: Multiplying by 100% is a no-op.

Comment: There's no such thing as multiplying by "100 percent". If you need to convert something to %, you simply multiply by 100 and that's basic maths.

Comment: i just forgot, ok thanks

Comment: As noted below `<=` is a boolean operator.  Semantically, therefore `double result = n/n*100 <= 100;` is logically equivalent to `boolean result = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing the value of `n / n * 100` to 100, the result would be a boolean (true/false).

If you want to accomplish something with this, you would do something like this:

```
double result = (n / n) * 1; //Because 100% is = to 1

    if(result <= 1){
        //Do stuff
    }
```

If you wanted to use a different percentage, then you would just replace 1 with the difference of 1 and that percentage. For example, if your percentage was 75%, then you would multiply by 0.75.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two operations, the first one is a math operation, it is before to the '<='. The second one, is a boolean operation, so you should think what is the purpose of that inequality (show the boolean result or the math result).

On the other hand, if you want to store that result you should do this:

```
boolean result = n/n * 100 <= 100;
```

Because, it is an inequality.